# Cross validation with specified number of training data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, k-fold

#### Objective

I want to perform k-fold cross-validation, but instead of using k-1 dataset for training and k dataset for test, I want to determine the number of training data, exactly like `train_test_split` 's `train_size`. Then the remainder as test data.

To be precise I have binary classification dataset, and I want 10 instances of each class when doing cross val.

### Expected Function

Let's say I want to do 5-fold CV:

`cross_val_score(estimator=my_model, X, y, cv=5, train_size=20)`

And of course in this case my X, y should have >= 100 instances.

#### My Attempt

Well I just built them manually. The closest I can get is iterating:

```
for _ in range (5):    
  X_tr, X_te, y_tr, y_te = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=20, stratified=y)
```

But this randomly picks the data and may result in two train dataset being alike, plus it doesn't accommodate cv.

#### Note

Yes, this will result in some dataset not being used for the training set, but that is what I want to achieve in my current work.

Is there any python function that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use [KFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html), but with additional logic.

Determine the amount of the test data: `test_amount = total_amount * test_size`.

Determine the **amount of the splits**: `n_splits = total_amount // test_amount`.

Use Kfolds:

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=n_splits)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```